# Question about type inference when using Generic and rest parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

This question is to, more than anything else, quench my curiosity and deepen my understanding regarding the inner workings of typescript's type inference when working with Generics.

**The Problem**

I wanted to create a higher-order function that adds additional arguments to a received function:

```js
type WithConfirmProps = {
  action: Function;
  text: string;
}

type CustomFunction<P> = (arg: P) => void

export function withConfirm<P>(innerFunction: CustomFunction<P>) {
  const wrappedFunction = ({ action, text, ...rest }: P & WithConfirmProps) => {
    // ...
    // code that uses action and text...

    rest; // inferred type is 'Pick<P & WithConfirmProps, Exclude<keyof P, "action" | "text">>'
    // but I expected it to be simply 'P', 
    // or at least that the 'Exclude' would be applied to 'WithConfirmProps', not to 'P'

    return innerFunction(rest); 
    //        error here ˆˆˆˆ is:
    //   Argument of type 'Pick<P & WithConfirmProps, Exclude<keyof P, "action" | "text">>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'P'.
    //     'P' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Pick<P & WithConfirmProps, Exclude<keyof P, "action" | "text">>'.(2345)
  };
​
  return wrappedFunction;
}
```

I found the error message somewhat of hard to understand, but after some thought, my interpretation of the problem was:

> The type `P` itself could have the properties `action` and `text`, that's why `rest` could not be inferred as `P`

**My Solution**

Based on the interpretation above, I tried to convey to the compiler that the Generic `P` did not had, in fact, the `action` and `text` properties.

The following snippet shows no compilation errors:

```js
export function withConfirm<P>(innerFunction: CustomFunction<Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, 'action' | 'text'>>>) {
  const wrappedFunction = ({ action, text, ...rest }: P & WithConfirmProps) => {
    // ...
    // code that uses action and text...

    rest; // type is Pick<P & WithConfirmProps, Exclude<keyof P, "action" | "text">>
    
    return innerFunction(rest); // 'rest' has exactly the same inferred type, 
    // but now it does not error ‍♂️
  };
​
  return wrappedFunction;
}
```

*You can reproduce this problem in this [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgYQPYDsBmcBOBbABR1TAGcoBeKAbwFgAoKKAQwGNg4MAuKAMQFd07TugDcDJsAgAPYD1LAccdAHNx9AL4MGoSFGT8FqPAKEcMAHgIA+SlAAUzHCp4EAlJVsA3VHAAm2vQyYKg4wFCYgsIYUADuCCgY2PgAjFbW9sroEDim0eg8BkYmUebo6R50jFCsGApxOMxgkH55ZXb21Cz5ADRQUrJ9AHQjOBD1Gq5QAGSwCWhYuITEZB4UtlVMTAD02zWoftBIzOGG493tzOh+-TLAI0OBW1Bj9bv94NBw5ARwrADWVhmcyQC2SyxIpD6AFFpKwADb8Q4Wf4QECoTBQAh9ABEbDKOKgAB8oDiBsAcdZrBItjSmGNgPwcOgoFkcm0RPZXsA3KIoHSoO8csQcKzSFwBe8oABBZz8PAQdDhDEfPQAcl+AKBs3goKSSyIkJhcMRyNR6Mx2NJ+JEhJJZLulOsarFUHQqHCzFIpDgKnQzAARvCjqgoGAnMwFVJRSrdNANWrHtUdnstgn9vx4TcA190AorhwThAbvEkCwWU4AwhGjgQKroLFEH9EBms1Ac1BBGN4UWbsBQxq-oCCMDdYlFvhDWRjQikRAUWiVVa8fk7aTyU7E-YAEwAZgALABWNyBGkadSAaAIaQymSzYo1msWORh1Fp6AxgqFwpEzCI4vN9Xwbd0kydBslyUoREKQx+xKX9LE1YcZ1NedzSXPo1RtDAXRJNVyTVKlrEqGlajzcJ7yaFpnxZKhOguEQ+nJYZRnGcJJixUcAInCFVk8GhJT2WpDn6RATk7UhziwitrluWQHieLZuUFPY41dRDtRBcdwSnKEoFhWczUXS1cSktcHVkJ0BQFG9mVZMD2UgjAuVY3l+Wqc8GCvaobLvB8qMcsQGA0IA)*

---

- **Question 1**: Was my interpretation of the error correct?
- **Question 2**: Is there a better way to type the functions?

Answer (score 0):

> The type P itself could have the properties `action` and `text`, that's why `rest` could not be inferred as `P`

This is exactly it.  The `rest` variable created by your object destructuing will never contain properties `action` and `text`.  If `innerFunction` requires a type which has an `action` or `text` property, then `rest` will not be assignable to this type because it will be missing those properties.

You've fixed in in your second example by ruling out this possibility.  You've said that regardless of what type `P` is, `innerFunction` absolutely cannot require an object with properties `action` or `text`.  So when we drop those properties we don't have to worry that `rest` is missing anything that `innerFunction` expects.

Another way to deal with it that looks cleaner is to move the destructuring inside of the function body.  That way we can call `innerFunction` with the entire `props` object instead of `rest`.  We already know that `props` is assignable to `P` and we don't have to worry about any dropped properties.

```
export function withConfirm<P>(innerFunction: CustomFunction<P>) {
    const wrappedFunction = (props: P & WithConfirmProps) => {
        const { action, text } = props;

        // do stuff with action and text...

        return innerFunction(props);
    };

    return wrappedFunction;
}
```

An advantage of your second approach over what I've written above is that it makes it clear which inner functions are going to cause problems.

```
const inner = ({action}: {action: string}) => action
```

Consider the above function `inner` for which `P` is `{action: string}`.  We don't get any errors when we wrap in in the higher-order function.

```
const wrapped = withConfirm(inner);
```

But we've created a function `wrapped` that expects to be called with `P & WithConfirmProps` aka `{action: string}` & `{action: Function; text: string;}` and that's impossible.  You can never call this function because you'll always get an error that your `action` argument is `not assignable to type 'string & Function'`.

With your typing of `innerFunction: CustomFunction<Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, 'action' | 'text'>>>`, you would get an error at the point where you try to wrap the function.  So I think you've done a good job with your typings.  I would write it as `innerFunction: CustomFunction<Omit<P, keyof WithConfirmProps>>` to avoid the string literals, but it evaluates to the same thing.